# sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedColumnError:Couldnot initializetargetcolumnforForeignKey 'user.id' ontable 'student_data':table 'user'hasnocolumnnamed 'id'

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

Database :

```
class User(db.Model):

    id = db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True) 

    username = db.Column(db.String(100))

    email = db.Column(db.String(100))

    password = db.Column(db.String(100))

    def init(self, username, email, password):

        self.username = username

        self.email = email

        self.password = password

class TrainingData(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    input = db.Column(db.Text)

    output = db.Column(db.Text)

class StudentData(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False) 

    question = db.Column(db.Text)

    answer = db.Column(db.Text)

    result = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

Code:

```
@app.route('/exam', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def exam():

    if 'user_id' not in session:

        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    training_data = TrainingData.query.order_by(db.func.random()).all()

    questions = [data.input for data in training_data]

    answers = [data.output for data in training_data]

    ind_of_que_ans = random.sample(range(len(questions)), len(questions))

    random_questions = [questions[i] for i in ind_of_que_ans]

    if request.method == 'POST':

        questions_scores = []

        current_user_id = session['user_id']

        for i in ind_of_que_ans:

            text1 = answers[i]

            text2 = request.form[f'question{i}']

            prompt = f"Text 1: {text1}\nText 2: {text2} two text has the same meaning:\n"

            response = palm.generate_text(

                **defaults,

                prompt=prompt

            )   

            similarity_score = 0  

            if text2 != "":

                if response.result:

                    similarity_text = response.result.lower()

                    if 'yes' in similarity_text:

                        similarity_score = 2

                    elif 'no' in similarity_text:

                        similarity_score = 0

                    student_data_entry = StudentData(user_id=current_user_id, question=random_questions[i], answer=text2, result=similarity_score)

                    db.session.add(student_data_entry)

            else:

                similarity_score = 0

            questions_scores.append(similarity_score)

        score = sum(questions_scores)

        current_user = User.query.get(current_user_id)

        #db.session.commit()

        return render_template('doctor_questions.html', questions=random_questions, indexes=ind_of_que_ans, score=score, scores=questions_scores, count=len(questions) * 2, userId=current_user.id, userName=current_user.username)

    return render_template('exam.html', questions=random_questions, indexes=ind_of_que_ans)


Error : current_user = User.query.get(current_user_id)
```

Code:

```
class User(db.Model):

    tablename = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    username = db.Column(db.String(100))

    email = db.Column(db.String(100))

    password = db.Column(db.String(100))

    student_data = db.relationship("StudentData", back_populates="user", primaryjoin="User.id == StudentData.user_id")

    def init(self, username, email, password):

        self.username = username

        self.email = email

        self.password = password

class TrainingData(db.Model):

    tablename = 'training_data'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    input = db.Column(db.Text)

    output = db.Column(db.Text)

class StudentData(db.Model):

    tablename = 'student_data'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)

    question = db.Column(db.Text)

    answer = db.Column(db.Text)

    result = db.Column(db.Integer)

    user = db.relationship("User", back_populates="student_data", primaryjoin="User.id == StudentData.user_id")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.  That said, shouldn't that ```student_data``` table's  ForeignKey be defined with ```User.id```?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.